# Hibernate Criteria API & Subset

Tags: hibernate, criteria, subset, subquery

first of all, I'm new to Hibernate.

Let's say we've got a data structure like the following:

Entity A has 0 .. * associated Bs. One of these Bs may has an attribute "isDefault" set to true. For every A, only one B exists at max with this attribute set to true.

I want to get all As with their default Bs (if exists), otherwise B is supposed to be null. Here's what I got until now:

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(A.class);

c.createCriteria("bs").add(Restrictions.eqOrIsNull("isDefault", true));
```

Of course, this will result in all As having a default B with all Bs of A attached to A.

I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to try something like "get all A where B is null or B have field 'isDefault' set to true":

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(A.class);
Disjunction disjunction = Restrictions.disjunction();
c.add(disjunction);
disjunction.add(Restrictions.isNull("bs"));
c.createAliase("bs", "b");
disjunction.add(Restrictions.eq("b.isDefault", true));
```

Please follow this link: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly.

It doesn't really depend on whether the subset of all Bs is null or not. I need to get all As. If any Bs are attached to any of these A, only the B should be attached/shown to A which is default for the A.